# EXR Artefacts / Lensdistortion STMap to Nuke / 3D Tracking

Tags: compositing-nodes, .exr

I bumpt into a STMap artifacts problem

In Nuke i generate a plate

red      (x+0.5)/width
 green    (y+0.5)/height"
 blue      0
 alpha     1
 [image: STMap undistorted]

Format is EXR 32bit zip1

In Blender I undistort it with the tracking result and render it out as an EXR 32bit zip1
[image: Blender undistort STMap generation]

When I use this STMap for lens distortion in Nuke then i get artifacts
[image: top artifacts, lower clean render from blender]

The lower and clean part of the image is the lens distortion applied directly in Blender.

Artifacts only appear when i render a EXR. Tiff does not have that problem, but does not allow linear workflow nor is it 32bit.

Something I found in an other Forum:
https://www.mail-archive.com/nuke-users@support.thefoundry.co.uk/msg12365.html
Quote from this thread:
¨Just to follow up. I spoke with the folks at Imagineer and they said the issues with distortion maps were fixed in v4, but it's possible that exr's are still affected. Tiff's are being rendered correctly from Mocha Pro v4 at 32-bit and the aliasing problem has disappeared.¨

What I'm doing wrong. Is there a faulty implementation of the EXR code?

Thank you for your help.

Differencemap Tiff vs. EXR:
[image: Difference Tiff vs. EXR - should be black]

This image heavy gamma lifted to show the differences in the picture. Ideally if everything works as expected with EXR the image should be black (RGB 0,0,0).

Comment: Although I am completely unfamiliar with your particular software and issue, could you explain what the exact error you are seeing is? Is it the shearing across the image? Part of the issue would be properly decoding the JPEG, and linearizing the nonlinear encoding. Hard to know exactly where the potential breakage is, as there are many points that could snap.

Comment: Hi Troy
The last picture with the car shows it clearly. The upper part is blocky or shows artifacts, the lower part of the picture is how it should look.

This gives you an overview:
https://vfx-rants.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-stmap-based-deformations-for-lens.html

Comment: Guessing you are ingesting an EXR? Regardless, are you flagging the image buffer as non-color data?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option (non-color data) in Blender when you load a single image to the compositor. I'm not going through the Shader Editor.
This workflow is not limited to lens distortion: it can also be applied to bend and warp objects in compositing that are behind a rendered (CG) transparent object (IOR).

How can I provide more help? pm?

Comment: Open image editor, properties. You set the colourspace there. It’s dumb, yes.

Comment: I’m not sure what the issue is just yet, but it would start with evaluating the encoded data within Blender. That is, if the EXRs the software is making are broken, then using the TIFF encoding correctly and doing an A/B test against the encoded values is where I’d start. Compare the float values inside the file with what is reported.

Comment: Colorspace to non-color data does not change it. Tiff works like expected. I made a difference map from EXR vs. Tiff: it's the last picture in the main post.
This picture should be completely black.

Comment: I strongly suspect the EXR is not being encoded correctly in the source software. I would create a test EXR with known values and see if it is encoded correctly. It sure feels like broken EXR encoding.

Comment: I managed it to get an EXR that works. It was always there, I was just using the one that was rendered from the output (under Stereoscopy). Even it had the exact same settings it was a lot smaller in size.
The one that comes out from the fileoutput in compositor works now. - what brings the next question up?: How to render the overscan in the exr. It is cropped to the resolution of the project. - maybe I open an other thread.

Comment: Definitely worth another thread! Happy the issue was diagnosed.